A method inside ngOnInit is not called during testing
I'm trying to test if a service method is called from ngOnInit. However, I get a strange behavior: the method is not called although ngOnInit is executed.
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { SampleService } from './sample.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sample',
  templateUrl: './sample.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sample.component.css']
})
export class SampleComponent {
  todos:any;

  constructor(private service: SampleService){}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.todos = 'A';
    this.service.getAll().subscribe(
      res => {
        this.todos = res;
      }
    );
  }
}

describe('SampleComponent', () => {
  let component: SampleComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<SampleComponent>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ HttpClientModule ],
      declarations: [ SampleComponent ],
      providers: [ SampleService ]
    })
    .compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SampleComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should load todos from the server', () => {
    let todos = [1,2,3];
    let service = TestBed.inject(SampleService);
    spyOn(service,'getAll').and.returnValue(of(todos));
    
    fixture.detectChanges();
    //component.ngOnInit();
    
    expect(component.todos).toEqual(todos);
  });
  
});

If I test this code, the test fails and it return the message "Expected 'A' to equal [ 1, 2, 3 ]". So 'ngOnInit' is executed but the method 'getAll' is not called.
However, if I uncomment 'component.ngOnInit()', so I call ngOnInit manually, the test works perfectly (it returns a SUCCESS message).
Do you understand why this happens? Why getAll is not called?
More information:
I tried to edit my test to make it easier to understand the issue. Now I use toHaveBeenCalledWith() to test if the method is called. And, like I supposed, it is not called at all, even though ngOnInit is executed. With the following test I get the message: Expected spy getAll to have been called once. It was called 0 times. However, uncommenting component.ngOnInit(), the method is called.
  it('should load todos from the server', () => {
    let todos = [1,2,3];
    let service = TestBed.inject(SampleService);
    let spy = spyOn(service,'getAll').and.returnValue(of(todos));

    fixture.detectChanges();
    //component.ngOnInit();

    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });


I found a solution, so I decided to answer my own question.
I just copied the definition of fixture and component instance in my it() method. So I redefine them before calling spyOn and before executing fixture.detectChanges(). Doing so, it works.
it('should load todos from the server', () => {
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SampleComponent);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
  let todos = [1,2,3];
  let service = TestBed.inject(SampleService);
  spyOn(service,'getAll').and.returnValue(of(todos));

  fixture.detectChanges();

  expect(component.todos).toEqual(todos);
});

I don't know whether this is a good practice or not, but for now it seems the only way to test ngOnInit as integration test.

You are trying to test asynchronous call but doing it synchronously. By the time expect is executed, your of() mock isn't. That's why you're not seeing results.
You can "wrap" your test func into the fakeAsync and combine it with tick which does its own tricks to simulate passage of time.
it('should load todos from the server', fakeAsync(() => {
  let todos = [1,2,3];
  let service = TestBed.inject(SampleService);
  spyOn(service,'getAll').and.returnValue(of(todos));
  
  // I don't recall by heart if you need to call ngOnInit or not. Give it a try I guess
  //component.ngOnInit(); 
  tick();
  expect(component.todos).toEqual(todos);
}));

See this for more info on the topic.

Thank you for your reply. However, this solution doesn't seem to work. I did other tries but it seems that the method is not called (you can see my last update in the first post).
